# Where can I find the onmessage listener of an embedded jms?

Tags: java, jms

We have a large application and we are having an issue. I have to modify the message received by our embedded jms, but unlike other I can't find where is the listener of our jms. Can someone give me a tip where to find the onMessage method that receives message? And is it possible to receive a message without implementation of onMessage?

Answer (score 0):

I would open up the interface MessageInterface and look for implementers of that interface in your project.  Then look for anything in your project's packages first.  If you don't find any then I'd look for other implementations and research how they work.  Maybe the wrap some other part of your codebase with a different interface that you can do the same technique on it.

With IDEs like IntelliJ and Eclipse doing this code search is simple (over say using text searching).

There is always a possibility that your embedded JMS allows you to register against proprietary interfaces, but if that's true then we can't answer your question without knowing the specific embedded implementation you are using.